# C# SQL - new login sees all databases

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that created a database and a user specific for that database (local).

I can create a user with rights only to that database, but that user can see every other database and users.
The query that I use is the following

```
CREATE DATABASE Devcom2;
GO
USE TEST;
GO
CREATE SCHEMA Devcom2;
GO
CREATE LOGIN Devcom2 WITH PASSWORD = '1234852';
EXEC sp_defaultdb @loginame='Devcom2', @defdb='1234852'
CREATE USER Devcom2 FOR Devcom2 TEST_USER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Devcom2;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','Devcom2'
GO
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This

    CREATE DATABASE Devcom2;
    GO
    USE Devcom2;
    GO
    CREATE SCHEMA Devcom2;
    GO
    CREATE LOGIN Devcom2 WITH PASSWORD = '1234852';
    EXEC sp_defaultdb @loginame='Devcom2', @defdb='Devcom2'
    CREATE USER Devcom2 For LOGIN Devcom2 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Devcom2
    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner','Devcom2'
    GO


http://www.sqlteachers.com/entries/2014-Creating-a-Database-and-Assigning-a-user-to-it
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a database `Devcom2`, but you `USE TEST`.

Change your code to

```
CREATE DATABASE Devcom2;
GO
USE Devcom2;
```